# pg_ctl: no operation specified

Tags: postgres-xc

I tried to start postgresql server using pg_ctl with following command:

```
    pg_ctl -D /opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/data start
```

causes following error message:

```
    Postgres-XC: must start as either a Coordinator (--coordinator) or Datanode (--datanode)
```

So I made some changes to the command, namely

```
    pg_ctl -D /opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/data -Z "Coordinate" start
```

which causes

```
    pg_ctl: no operation specified
```

I have searched on the web and found no answer. How can I start the server correctly?

Comment: I don't know Postgres-XC but the error message mentions `--coordinator` not, `-Z "Coordinate"`